# If I leave the quest area will enemies respawn?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

When I am in a quest sometime I go searching for some healing plants, or I hide from some robots (not far away I am still near the quest area).

I noticed when I get back to the original area, the robots that I have killed have re-spawned - it's like I am repeating the mission again.

Why is it that if I leave the quest area for a minute, the robots/humans that I have killed re-spawn? Is this normal?

Comment: It depends how much near. You shouldn't leave a quest area, if you need to heal you have your herbs stockpile or potions.

Comment: @pinckerman i was a building away from the quest , I was hiding from the robots , when i get back all of them returned. so its normal ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it depends on the quest. In most cases, they seem to never respawn, but in at least one quest that I encountered (find out more about the mysterious woman at the site where Olin mentioned), they respawn, like you said, even just being a building away. It is very frustrating, to the point that it did seem like perhaps bug.

Comment: When you reach 50 rep you can comment on posts, saying you experienced the same thing, and not providing a solution is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, the enemies will only respawn if you fast travel out of that area come back again with the help of a bonfire. If you simply go away from the quest area to collect other items and come back, then you will find it in the same condition as when you left it, i.e. the enemies killed and all the destruction you made earlier.